Ubuntu 24.04 won't boot after install with wiping win 10
Installed Ubuntu 24.01 from USB drive on Win10 machine.
During install, selected download new version installer.
Option of dual OS install was not given.
I did not select option of changing partitions, because this is new to me.
Selected wipe win10 and start over with Ubuntu.
That was fine with me,as I am trying to get away from everything Microsoft.
After install, machine does not boot.
Tried selecting various options in Bios, no help.
I am new at this, and may have made some wrong selections in bios setup.
Installed Ubuntu again, this time WITHOUT the new version installer.
Now I was given the option of side-by side OS, selected that.
Installer divided my 1TB drive in halves, now I have two instances of 24.01 each in its own partition!
Machine still won't boot.
I tried:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
returns:
E: Invalid operation boot-repair
In order to access this help system,I inserted Ubuntu USB, and as far as I can tell, I am running off of it, and not from my HD.
Response to first comment>>>
Most of  your terminology I do not understand. Can you simplify? I did select one of the partitions containing Ubuntu to  be Bootable, using DISKS. It is now flagged boot, esp, and legacy boot, shown in GParted, but does not boot. I am running off the USB.
Now downloading boot-repair-disk.
Beginning to understand ...
Please help,and thank you!
~Mark

Did you install in UEFI boot mode. How you boot installer is how it installs. What brand/model system? Did you add the ppa for Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Use your Ubuntu live installer & click on the link for instructions on using ppa to install & run Boot-Repair. What brandmodel system? You choose UEFI or BIOS every time you boot from USB live installer. Always chose UEFI. And setting for UEFI or BIOS/Legacy/CSM is for installed system which should then be in UEFI boot mode.

This is a DELL Inspiron with Intel Core i3 8th gen., made in 2018.
I do not recall seeing the options to use ppa to install and run Boot-Repair during installation, nor any choice offered to use UEFI or BIOS.
I ran this in Terminal:
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update
Repository: 'Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/
Suites: noble
Components: main
'
... which loaded many lines of code, but I don't see how to run the Repair-Disk program.
Download of boot-repair-disk keeps failing. Slow internet today.

Thank you all for your help.
I ran a wipe-and clean install of Ubuntu, and all is well now.
